# An event to know when the HTML5 video is ready to played without black background

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I have videos, sounds and images in an application I am creating. To display videos , I am suing the "video for all" format. But the problem is , it takes time for the video to load. I have added all kinds of event handlers, `loadeddata` , `readystatechange`, `canplay` , `canplaythrough`, `loadedmetadata` everything I could possibly could have tried. But all events occur before I actually see the poster of the video(untll which the background is black) and when It actually is loaded practically. How do I get to know when the video is actually ready to be played ?( I mean ACTUALLY )

The below function is called like this

```
$video = getVideoObj({
                    //'controls' : 'controls',
                    'width': '100%',
                    'height': '100%',
                    'mediaUrl': appSettings.is_dev ? devMediaUrl + 'video/' + videoname
                                    : appSettings.site_url + 'resolve_path/' + mediaFilesUuid   + '/media/video/' + videoname
                }),



getVideoObj = function (videoProperties) {

    var controlsText = (videoProperties.controls && videoProperties.controls == "controls") ? "controls='" + videoProperties.controls + "'" : "",
        $video = $('<video/>', {
            'width': videoProperties.width,
            'height': videoProperties.height
        }),
        mp4Src = (videoProperties.mediaUrl).replace('mov', 'mp4'),
        $sourceMp4 = $('<source/>', {'src': mp4Src, 'type': 'video/mp4' }),
        webmSrc = (videoProperties.mediaUrl).replace('mov', 'webm'),
        $sourcewebm = $('<source/>', { 'src': webmSrc, 'type': 'video/webm'}),
        oggSrc = (videoProperties.mediaUrl).replace('mov', 'theora.ogv'),
        $sourceOgg = $('<source/>', {'src': oggSrc,'type': 'video/ogg' }),
        $object = $('<object/>', {
            'type': 'application/x-shockwave-flash',
            'data': 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf',
            'width': videoProperties.width,
            'height': videoProperties.height
        }),
        $param1 = $('<param/>', {
            'name': 'movie',
            'value': 'http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf'
        }),
        $param2 = $('<param/>', {
            'name': 'allowFullScreen',
            'value': 'true'
        }),
        $param3 = $('<param/>', {
            'name': 'wmode',
            'value': 'transparent'
        }),
        playlistObject = {
            'playlist': [
                '', {
                    'url': '',
                    'autoPlay': false
                }
            ]
        },
        $param4 = $('<param/>', {
            'name': 'flashVars',
            'config': playlistObject
        }),
        $img = $('<img/>', {
            'alt': 'Big Buck Bunny ',
            'src': 'http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/images/big-buck-bunny_poster.jpg',
            'width': videoProperties.width,
            'height': videoProperties.height,
            'title': 'No video playback capabilities, please download the video below'
        });

    if (controlsText !== "") {
        $video.attr("controls", controlsText);
    }
    var video = $video.get(0);
    video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
        function checkLoad() {
            console.log("video.readyState ",video.readyState);
            if (video.readyState === 4) {
                console.log("ready");
            } else {
                setTimeout(checkLoad, 100);
            }
        }
        checkLoad();
    }, false);
    video.addEventListener("canplay", function () {
        console.log("Video can be played");
    }, false);

    video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function () {
        vLength = video.duration.toFixed(1);
        console.log(vLength);
    }, false);

    video.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        console.log(video.readyState);
        if (videoreadyState ===4) {
            console.log("Ready state");
        }
    }, false);

    video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
        console.log("Can play through");
    }, false);
    video.addEventListener('load', function () {
        console.log("Loaded");
    }, false); //add load event as well to avoid errors, sometimes 'canplaythrough' won't dispatch.

    video.addEventListener('progress',function (e) {
        console.log('PROGRESS',e);
    },false);
    $object.append($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $img);
    $video.append($sourceOgg, $sourceMp4, $sourcewebm, $object);
    return $video;
}
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: @Raptor Here it is now

Comment: okay, read your codes. You used some JS libraries; please mention it in question. Also, please paste the console output here. And, can I assume the code is wrapped within `document.ready` function? If I were you, I will use `VideoJS` library, which can achieve your goal in few lines.

Comment: I am only using **jQuery** as a library here , since I have to display videos with different properties multiple times in the page , I made this function which is called some times , this is how i use the function

Comment: Yes , Probably correct !! I also Read ```MediaElement.js``` , which one is better ?

Comment: won't answer opinion-based question, but you can try it out yourself.

Comment: put the image in front of (document order) the video and hide the image oncanplay, otherwise it won't be shown until the video loads...

Answer (score -2):

Just use a simple video play in html5

```
 <video id="video1" width="420" controls>
    <source src="http://corrupt-system.de/assets/media/sintel/sintel-trailer.m4v" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="pjds.ogg" type="video/ogg">  
  </video>
```